# How to store and write over JTEXTField java

Tags: java, calculator

My question is how do I write in a jtextfield then store the input and the write in it again. For example a gui calculator

I want to do 2+4=6

so I click the 2 button then the + button (i know how to get 2 stored but the 2 needs to remain in the textfield until another number is pressed)

so it would be like

Button = 2 TextField = 2

button =+ Tf = 2

but =4 tf = 4

but = + tf = 6

then from there go on and be able to press +,-,/,* and it just continue in the same way.

so we continue the example

but = + tf = 6

but = * tf = 6

but =2 tf = 6

but = tf = 12

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this isn't a site where you ask us to do **your** homework, first you need to try to do something yourself, start taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) then learn [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and lastly How to make a [runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then come back here with an specific question and your code. This will lead to more, faster and better responses and less confusion. Once you have done this, and if your question is still open, edit it adding the above recommendations or ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to call the JTextField's `setText()` method:

```
JTextField text = new JTextField();
text.setText("6");
text.setText("*");
text.setText("2");
text.setText("12");
```

You will obviously make these calls in the action listener attatched to your buttons (doing it like this will just leave the text field with a value of 12, and you won't see the other values), but calling the `setText()` method repeatedly will each time replace the value that's in the text field.